# Char* showing null when it shouldn't

Tags: c, null, scanf

In this function I wrote for a book database program, I get the user to input a book identifier and it should then go and search the linkedlist for that book and display it's details.

The **identifierTemp** variable is initialized as *NULL* but when the user inputs their desired book's identifier, the **identifierTemp** remains as *NULL*?!?!

Here's the function. Hopefully someone can spot my mistake. Thanks in advance.

```
void viewBook() {

    printf("\n*** VIEW A BOOK ***\n");

    struct node *currentBook, *prevBook;

    bool notFound = true;

    char* identifierTemp = NULL;

    //user input
    printf("\nBook Identifier: ");
    scanf("%s", identifierTemp);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("\n");

    if (isEmpty())
        printf("Error - there are no books in the list\n\n\n");
    else  {
        currentBook = prevBook = firstBook;

        while (notFound && currentBook != NULL) {

            if (identifierTemp == currentBook->element->identifier)
                notFound = false;
            else {
                    prevBook = currentBook;
                    currentBook = currentBook->next;
            }//end else

        } //end while

        if (notFound)
            printf("Error - there is not such book with the identifier %s\n\n\n", identifierTemp);

        else  {

            //DISPLAY ALL BOOK DETAILS
            printf("\n\nIdentifier: %s", currentBook->element->identifier);
            printf("\nTitle: %s", currentBook->element->title);
            printf("\nAuthor: %s", currentBook->element->author);
            printf("\nYear: %d", currentBook->element->year);
            printf("\nStatus (1 = not available to take out): %d", currentBook->element->status);
            printf("\nCustomer: %s", currentBook->element->customer);
            printf("\nTimes Taken Out: %d", currentBook->element->timesTakenOut);
            printf("\nGenre: %s", currentBook->element->genre);
            } //end else

            printf("\n");

       }//end else

    menuSystem();//return to the menu

}//end ViewBook
```

Console output:

```
*** VIEW A BOOK ***

Book Identifier: *USER INPUT HERE*

Error - there is no such book with the identifier (null)
```

Comment: Never call `fflush(stdin)` - it's UB on most platforms. Also you need to allocate some memory for `identifierTemp` - `scanf` can't/won't do it for you!

Comment: And `identifierTemp == currentBook->element->identifier` is comparing pointers, not the strings. Use `strcmp`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to give `identifierTemp` some memory so `scanf` has somewhere to put the data

i.e. change it to

```
char identifierTemp[4096]; // Or some other size that can reasonably store the string.
```

The re-read the manual page on `scanf` so that limit will not be exceeded

Answer (score 1):

After you allocate memory properly for your `identifierTemp` you also need to compare strings properly. This code:

```
identifierTemp == currentBook->element->identifier
```

Compares the string addresses (pointers) and will not ever be true. You need to use `strcmp`:

```
if (strcmp(identifierTemp, currentBook->element->identifier) == 0)
    notFound = false;
```

By the way, the double negative is a bit distasteful. Why not make the boolean be `Found = false` to start and then set `Found = true` when you find it.